# WebView scroll up automatically when scrolling it down little

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-webview

In web view when I scroll the page little bit down then it scroll up automatically on some pages not all pages but on some pages.Why this happen and what is it solution
Here is xml code

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout android:id="@+id/nonVideoLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    >
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is my code you can check this

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
        bindLayout();
        mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                webView.reload();
            }
        });
        CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(url, cookie);
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        ProgressDialogHelper.showProgress(WebViewActivity.this);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    view.loadUrl(url);



                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {

                mySwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

            webView.loadUrl(url);

    }
```

Here is my java code I set the cookie also to web view and I set also layer type. I search that everyone says to set layer type then this problem solved but it does not solved.

Comment: put java code, i think its happening because of SwipeRefreshLayout, when you scroll down SwipeRefreshLayout event onRefresh got Fired.

Comment: so how I can overcome this

Comment: I added the code

Comment: webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
any specific reason for using above line?

Comment: no I just copy and paste it from stack overflow

Comment: after removing this the problem is still same

Comment: wait, let me check first

Comment: I even remove the swipe to refresh widget but I get even same

Comment: remove these too
  webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
final WebSettings settings = mWebView.getSettings();
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Comment: try to remove all of this

    CookieManager.getInstance().setCookie(url, cookie);
        webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

Comment: removing .setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); is okey for everything

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
webView.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

all others are OK

Answer (score 0):

try this in AndroidManifest.xml

set `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in the ***application*** and ***activity*** tag.