# the scrolling is working by reverse on WebView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-linearlayout, android-websettings

I used WebView in my app and it sees the scrolling is not working properly, when I trying to scroll down the page does not go down and the reverse is true, but when I try to touch the screen and get off in reverse "touch with scroll up" It's working!!, more clarification in this images [gif1](https://i.imgur.com/KjWTdAl.gifv) , [gif2](https://i.imgur.com/xCFAwTO.gifv)

**code**

```
public class VisitSiteFragment extends android.app.Fragment {

private View view;
private ProgressBar webViewProgressBar;
private WebView webView;
String url;


public VisitSiteFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_visit_site, container, false);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        url = this.getArguments().getString("url");
        Log.e("URL", url);
    }
    webViewProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.webViewProgressBar);
    webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);


    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            webViewProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        }
    });
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            webViewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            webViewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    });

    webView.loadUrl(url);

    return view;

}

}
```

**the XML**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".VisitSiteFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/webViewProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="8dp"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:theme="@style/progressBarBlue"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginTop="-3dp"
        android:progress="20"
        />

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

    </WebView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I saw someone asking about this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52234147/4205927), but the answer in that question did not help

Comment: can you please post all your code ? as i can see the progress bar is progressing reversely , so i need to read all your code please

Comment: @ismail alaoui the problem is not with progressBar it's working normally, anyway I'll edit the post to to include the fragment calss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts of WebView settings, I solved the issue by disabling scrolling that embedded with WebView as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5274400/4205927), and used ScrollView instead of it

The code after edited

```
webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

    webView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE);
        }
    });

    webView.setScrollContainer(false);


    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
            webViewProgressBar.setProgress(newProgress);
            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
        }
    });
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            webViewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            webViewProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

    });
```